# Java classpath and classloading

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I need load a jar file in runtime in Java and I have this code but it not load any jar  and I don't know how, somebody can tell me why? I have JVM 8 and NetBeans 8, the purpose is create a program that can load jar files as a plugins y for Windows.

```
package prueba.de.classpath;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class PruebaDeClasspath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("PluginNumeroUno");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }

        try {
            URLClassLoader classLoader = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader
                    .getSystemClassLoader());
            Method metodoAdd = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",
                    new Class[]{URL.class});
            metodoAdd.setAccessible(true);


            File file = new File("plugins/PrimerPlugins.jar");

            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            System.out.println(url.toURI().toURL());

            metodoAdd.invoke(classLoader, new Object[]{url});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("PluginNumeroUno");
            System.out.println("ok");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Provide your current System.out console output in the question

Comment: I get a feeling you are reinventing the wheel here. Exactly why would you need to manually load the jar-file? `java --classpath` not doing the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating new class loader instead of casting the system classloader.

Remove this line:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

and create the new loader and use it as below:

```
File file = new File("plugins/PrimerPlugins.jar");
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()},    
    PruebaDeClasspath.class.getClassLoader());
Class.forName("prueba.de.classpath.PluginNumeroUno", true, classLoader); //fully qualified!
```

Please note that the class name to be loaded has to be fully qualified.

You also don't have to dynamically force `addURL()` to be public.